# history.push in react router fires new request, nginx return 404

Tags: nginx, react-router, browser-history

I read a lot of questions about 'history.push nginx react-router' but I didn't find the solution for the problem I'm facing.

The problem is, when I log in my application in my Login component I do something like this after the ajax call is executed:

```
cb = (res) => {
  if (res.token!== null && res.token !== undefined){
    localStorage.setItem("token",res.token);
    localStorage.setItem("expiresIn",res.expiresIn);
    localStorage.setItem("email", res.email);
    **history.push('/home/0/0');**
  }else{this.setState({errorTextMail:"wrong mail or wrong password!"})}}
```

Locally it works fine but in the console the `history.push('/home/0/0')` fires a request that nginx doesn't handle and return 404, but in my browser the app log me in and I don't see the error.

Instead when I build the app and put the build folder under nginx to serve static files, when I try to login it show me the 404 page. Then if I refresh the page (removing the `/home/0/0` from the url) it works fine, recognize the token and log me in and I can browse other route of the app.

I was supposed that history.push would have been handled by react-router, just changing the component mapped by the appropriate `<Route path="/home/:idOne/:idTwo" component={Home} />` component and not firing a new request to nginx.

My question is, there is a way to switch compoent when the `cb` function return my token instead of using `history.push('/home/0/0')`?

Note the `history` object is defined this way

```
import history from './history';
```

and the history.js's content is :

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export default createHistory({
  forceRefresh: true
})
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What version of react?

Comment: react 15.4, react-router 4

Comment: window.location can be used too fyi